# docker-compose selectively thinks config.yml is a folder

Tags: github, docker-compose

I am running docker-compose 1.25.5 on a ubuntu 20 box and I have a github repo working "fine" in its home folder... I can docker-compose build and docker-compose up with no problem, and the container does what is expected. The github repo is current with the on-disk files.

As a test, however, I created a new folder, pulled the repo, and ran docker-compose build with no problem but when I tried to run docker-compose up, I get the following error:

```
Starting live_evidently_1 ... done
Attaching to live_evidently_1
evidently_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
evidently_1  |   File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
evidently_1  |     with open('config.yml') as f:
evidently_1  | IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'config.yml'
live_evidently_1 exited with code 1
```

config.yml on my host is a file (of course) and the docker-compose.yml file is unremarkable:

```
version: "3"

services:
  evidently:
    build: ../
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./config.yml:/app/config.yml
```

etc...
...

So, I am left with two inter-related problems. 1) Why does the test version of the repo fail and the original version is fine (git status is unremarkable, all the files I want on github are up to date), and 2) Why does docker-compose think that config.yml is a folder when it is clearly a file?   I would welcome suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bind mount type. To do this you have to use long  syntax.

Like this.

```
volumes:
 - type: bind
   source: ./config.yml
   target: /app/config.yml
```